# Transparent sphere particles surrounded by squares when above/below water shader

Tags: unity

I get this really strange effect in my builds, **and only in builds**, when particles intersect with/go under the water:

[image]
[image]

Supposed to look like:

[image]

I have no idea what to search for or what to look for, any clues?

EDIT:

Water shader causing issues (purchased asset, I've written the seller):

[image]

Particle used:

[image]
[image]

I've tried messing around with render queues and settings on the particle system, but no real luck.

EDIT: It seems if I disable the depth effects on the component in the editor, the issue dissapears. Here is code from the class "LPWDepthEffect"

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace LPWAsset {
    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    public class LPWDepthEffect : MonoBehaviour {

        static Dictionary<Camera, Camera> depthCams = new Dictionary<Camera, Camera>();
        static Dictionary<Camera, float> camState = new Dictionary<Camera, float>();
        static RenderTexture depthTex = null;

        static Shader depthShader = null;
        bool receiveShadows;
        static bool recursiveGuard;

        static bool hideObjects = true;

        public void Init(bool receiveShadows) {
            this.receiveShadows = receiveShadows;
        }

        public void OnWillRenderObject() {
            var act = gameObject.activeInHierarchy && enabled;
            if (!act || !GetComponent<Renderer>()) return;

            var material = GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial;
            if (!material || !material.HasProperty("_EdgeBlend")) return;

            Camera cam = Camera.current;
            if (!cam) return;

            bool hasDepth = material.GetFloat("_EdgeBlend") > 0.5f ||
                (material.HasProperty("_LightAbs") && material.GetFloat("_LightAbs") > 0.5f);

            if (hasDepth) cam.depthTextureMode |= DepthTextureMode.Depth;

            if (!receiveShadows || !hasDepth) return; // only when both depth + shadows

            // Render only once per camera
            float lastRender;
            if (camState.TryGetValue(cam, out lastRender)) {
                if (Mathf.Approximately(Time.time, lastRender) && Application.isPlaying) return;
                camState[cam] = Time.time;
            } else {
                camState.Add(cam, Time.time);
            }

            // Safeguard from recursive 
            if (recursiveGuard) return;
            recursiveGuard = true;

            // Rendertexture
            if (!depthTex) {
                depthTex = new RenderTexture(cam.pixelWidth, cam.pixelHeight, 24, RenderTextureFormat.Depth);
                depthTex.name = "__DepthTex" + GetInstanceID();
                depthTex.hideFlags = HideFlags.DontSave;
            }

            // Camera
            Camera depthCam = null;
            depthCams.TryGetValue(cam, out depthCam);
            if (!depthCam) { // catch both not-in-dictionary and in-dictionary-but-deleted-GO
                GameObject go = new GameObject("Water Depth Camera id" + GetInstanceID() + " for " + cam.GetInstanceID(), typeof(Camera));
                depthCam = go.GetComponent<Camera>();
                depthCam.enabled = false;
                depthCam.transform.position = transform.position;
                depthCam.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
                go.hideFlags = hideObjects ? HideFlags.HideAndDontSave : HideFlags.DontSave;
                depthCams[cam] = depthCam;
                depthCam.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.Depth;
            }

            int oldPixelLightCount = QualitySettings.pixelLightCount;
            QualitySettings.pixelLightCount = 0;
            float oldShadowDistance = QualitySettings.shadowDistance;
            QualitySettings.shadowDistance = 0;

            if (depthCam != null) {
                depthCam.farClipPlane = cam.farClipPlane;
                depthCam.nearClipPlane = cam.nearClipPlane;
                depthCam.orthographic = cam.orthographic;
                depthCam.fieldOfView = cam.fieldOfView;
                depthCam.aspect = cam.aspect;
                depthCam.orthographicSize = cam.orthographicSize;
                depthCam.depth = cam.depth - 0.1f;

                //Render
                depthCam.worldToCameraMatrix = cam.worldToCameraMatrix;
                depthCam.projectionMatrix = cam.projectionMatrix;
                depthCam.cullingMask = ~(1 << 4) & cam.cullingMask; // without water
                depthCam.targetTexture = depthTex;
                depthCam.transform.position = cam.transform.position;
                depthCam.transform.rotation = cam.transform.rotation;
                if(depthShader == null) {
                    depthShader = Shader.Find("Hidden/LPWRenderDepth");
                }
                depthCam.renderingPath = RenderingPath.VertexLit;
                depthCam.RenderWithShader(depthShader, "RenderType");
                GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.SetTexture("_DepthTexture", depthTex);
            }

            QualitySettings.pixelLightCount = oldPixelLightCount;
            QualitySettings.shadowDistance = oldShadowDistance;
            recursiveGuard = false;

        }

        // Cleanup all the objects we possibly have created
        void OnDisable() {
            if (depthTex) {
                Destroy_(depthTex);
                depthTex = null;
            }
            foreach (var kvp in depthCams) {
                Destroy_((kvp.Value).gameObject);
            }
            depthCams.Clear();
            camState.Clear();
        }

        public void Destroy_(Object o) {
            if (Application.isPlaying) Destroy(o);
            else DestroyImmediate(o);
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the DepthShader:

```
Shader "Hidden/LPWRenderDepth" {

    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        Pass {
            ZWrite On
            Lighting Off
            ColorMask 0

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 2.0

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata {
              float3 pos : POSITION;
            };

            struct v2f {
              float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata IN) {
              v2f o;
              o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN.pos);
              return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f IN) : SV_Target {
              return fixed4(0,0,0,0);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }

    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" }

        Pass {
            ZWrite Off
            Lighting Off
            ColorMask 0

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 2.0

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            float4 vert () : SV_POSITION {
              return float4(0,0,0,0);
            }

            fixed4 frag () : SV_Target {
              return fixed4(0,0,0,0);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }

    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="TransparentCutout" }

        Pass {
            ZWrite Off
            Lighting Off
            ColorMask 0

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 2.0

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            float4 vert () : SV_POSITION {
              return float4(0,0,0,0);
            }

            fixed4 frag () : SV_Target {
              return fixed4(0,0,0,0);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using particles in your project? How did you make the water/character? Is there a chance you are using particles for a "splashing" effect which just doesn't work on builds?

Comment: Can you please include enough details of your terrain, water, and particle setup (materials, shaders, etc) so that we can reproduce this effect in a new empty project? This will let us test solutions to be sure they work for your case. For starters, suspect #1 for squares around transparent objects is writing to the depth buffer when you shouldn't, so be sure to pay attention to where you're using transparent shaders, and what queue/order you're drawing in.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks I realize I didnt provide much info. I tried to update with what I think is relevant. Please let me know if something important is missing.

Comment: I realize now that the cause is the water shader, and since that is a purchased asset that I cannot share, it will be hard to debug this. I can only hope someone ran into something similar.

Comment: Can you study the water shader, and reproduce the same problem with your own shader that you can share here, without reproducing the paid asset in full?

Comment: @Majs we need to test your shader if you purchased it you can edit the shader and remove unnecessary part that produce this problem.can you send an Image before build.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali The reason I purchased the shader is because I know nothing about shaders. I wouldnt even know where to look for the code causing the issue. I uploaded an image of how its supposed to look.

Comment: @Majs so without any code I can't help you.but I guess problem is Blending because you have many particle and Blending will kill the performance.Instead of use Blending shaders use Alpha Cutout

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali I understand, I am trying to isolate the problem.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali Added some code

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali Could it be caused by the Shader.Find("...")? I think I stumbled upon that during my research earlier, that it might cause issues in builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by moving the shaders to the "Assets/Resources" folder, since the scripts use `Shader.Find("...")`

Answer (score -1):

Observing the problem, I believe the random quad projections in the water are actually the quads of the particles without their texture rendering correctly. i imagine that Shader.Find("...") was previously unable to find the texture to render onto each quad(if you don't know, a particle is an actual image, usually a blurry circle, mapped to a texture2D, mapped to a simple quad for performance speed), but would still render the quad and their respective color filters. I hope that sheds some light on the problem even though it was already solved.

Comment: I already added this as an answer 6 hours ago?

Comment: While shader.Find(...) Was mentioned as an answer, no reason was given. Comments in the question seemed to end at "maybe its the buffer". Stack exchange seeks to educate users rather than simply provide solutions. I offered my answer with elaboration on what was likely appearing, how it might be fixed, and why it appeared that way to begin with. Sorry if i missed that information somewhere else